# Binding problems .NET client to HPOM web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, binding

I would like to connect to a SOAP webservice (HP Operations Manager Incident Web Service) using a .NET client based on code generated by adding a service reference. The generated proxy creates a client that implements the `DuplexClientBase` class. The service is IIS hosted with a self-signed certificate and I need to sign in using basic authentication.

I ran into two problems trying to connect to this service:

- I have not yet been able to find the right binding configuration. Either the binding does not support duplex or https traffic with basic authentication.
- When adding a .NET 2.0 web service reference (the binding issue is not there) I am able to connect to the service but the “Action” header element which is required by the service and should look like `<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/enumeration/Enumerate</a:Action>` is not included in the header. When I create a SoapExtensions and inspect the contents of the `Action` property of the `SoapMessage` object in the `ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)` method it contains the right value but the property is not serialized in the message header.

I would like to know if any of you could suggest what to do:

- Proceed with a 2.0 legacy reference and find a way to add the Action element in the SOAP header. (eg adding a SoapExtension)
- Fix the binding a find a way to connect to the https site with faulty certificate (`wsDualHttpBinding`does not support HTTPS, `BasicHttpBinding` does not support duplex, `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` does not seem to work in a console application)
- Try to generate the code in a way that no duplex communication is required. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a .NET 2.0 client support WS Addressing. You can accomplish this by downloading and installing Webservice Enhancements 3.0 (WSE). http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089
When you add a reference to the Microsoft.Web.Services3 assembly and change the code generated by adding the web service reference. Change `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` into `Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol` and the code will support WS Adressing. The action element will now be added to the SOAP header.

Although this workaround does the job I still would prefer a WCF service reference connection.